# Reading from an HDF5 file: 3D data into 1D vector in memory

Tags: c++, hdf5

Is it possible to read a 3D array in an HDF5 file into a 1D array/vector in C++ using a specific memspace layout?

I tried:

```
H5File file(file_name, H5F_ACC_RDONLY);
DataSet dataset = file.openDataSet(dataset_name);
DataSpace dataspace = dataset.getSpace();
hsize_t dim[3];
dataspace.getSimpleExtentDims(dim, NULL);

hsize_t memdim[1];
memdim[0] = dim[0] * dim[1] * dim[2];
DataSpace memspace(1, memdim);

vector<float> data_out(memdim[0]);
// set the memory layout to 1D
dataset.read(data_out.data(), PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT, memspace, dataspace);
```

But the vector is not filled correctly. I thought there might be a default mapping. Maybe there isn't? How can I specify one?

Comment: Why do you mean by "the vector is not filled correctly"? Maybe that's the way you are indexing it which is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the issue is that even though you read into a 1D array, you still pass the 3D dataspace to the `read` method of `dataset`.

```
H5File file(file_name, H5F_ACC_RDONLY);
DataSet dataset = file.openDataSet(dataset_name);
DataSpace dataspace = dataset.getSpace();
hsize_t dim[3];
dataspace.getSimpleExtentDims(dim, NULL);

hsize_t memdim = dim[0] * dim[1] * dim[2];;

vector<float> data_out(memdim);
//use the same layout for file and memory
dataset.read(data_out.data(), PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT, dataspace, dataspace);
```